# SqlServer - Should return the same number of lines ? Except vs Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm try to return the lines of the first table, than doens't exists on the second table.

We use EXCEPT on the first code, and it's works, but we're trying another solution, with less cost.

The alternative for the EXCEPT that I found, was using LEFT JOIN with all columns in the ON clause, and where clause.

Solution With Except:

```
SELECT ISNULL(B.Id_Estabelecimento, A.Id_Estabelecimento) AS Id_Estabelecimento
    ,ISNULL(C.Id_Produto, A.Id_Produto) AS Id_Produto
    ,ISNULL(D.CodigoProcessamento, A.CodigoProcessamento) AS CodigoProcessamento
    ,ISNULL(D.Id_Operacao, A.Id_Operacao) AS Id_Operacao
    ,ISNULL(CodigoMCC, 0) AS CodigoMCC
FROM VINCULOSOPERACOESCOMPACTA A WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN RedesComposicao B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id_Rede = B.Id_Rede
LEFT JOIN Produtos C WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id_FantasiaBasica = C.Id_FantasiaBasica
LEFT JOIN PerfisOperacoes D WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id_Perfil = D.Id_Perfil
WHERE A.FlagAtivo = CAST(1 AS BIT)

EXCEPT

SELECT ID_ESTABELECIMENTO
    ,ID_PRODUTO
    ,CODIGOPROCESSAMENTO
    ,ID_OPERACAO
    ,CODIGOMCC
FROM VINCULOSOPERACOES WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Solution with Left Join:

```
SELECT ISNULL(B.Id_Estabelecimento, A.Id_Estabelecimento) AS Id_Estabelecimento
    ,ISNULL(C.Id_Produto, A.Id_Produto) AS Id_Produto
    ,ISNULL(D.CodigoProcessamento, A.CodigoProcessamento) AS CodigoProcessamento
    ,ISNULL(D.Id_Operacao, A.Id_Operacao) AS Id_Operacao
    ,ISNULL(CodigoMCC, 0) AS CodigoMCC
INTO #TEMPAUX
FROM VINCULOSOPERACOESCOMPACTA A WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN RedesComposicao B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id_Rede = B.Id_Rede
LEFT JOIN Produtos C WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id_FantasiaBasica = C.Id_FantasiaBasica
LEFT JOIN PerfisOperacoes D WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id_Perfil = D.Id_Perfil
WHERE A.FlagAtivo = CAST(1 AS BIT)

SELECT * FROM #TEMPAUX tab1 WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN VINCULOSOPERACOES tab2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON
    tab1.ID_ESTABELECIMENTO = tab2.ID_ESTABELECIMENTO AND
    tab1.ID_PRODUTO = tab2.ID_PRODUTO AND
    tab1.CODIGOPROCESSAMENTO = tab2.CODIGOPROCESSAMENTO AND
    tab1.ID_OPERACAO = tab2.ID_OPERACAO AND
    tab1.CODIGOMCC = tab2.CODIGOMCC
WHERE tab2.ID_ESTABELECIMENTO IS NULL AND 
tab2.ID_PRODUTO IS NULL AND 
tab2.CODIGOPROCESSAMENTO IS NULL AND
tab2.ID_OPERACAO IS NULL AND
tab2.CODIGOMCC IS NULL
```

I guess that the solutions are equivalent, but the first returns 381.477 rows, and the second 6.496.025. I spend some days analysing the query and searching solutions, and don't find what i'm missing in the second query.

Thank you if you read!

Comment: There is always `NOT EXISTS`, and you seem to like incorrect results anyway given you've [splashed `NOLOCK` about like confetti](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: `EXCEPT` returns unique records